# rspec-spies inspect the call arguments to stubbed methods and method spies

Tags: rspec, rspec2, rspec-rails, stub

I'm using [rspec-spies](https://github.com/technicalpickles/rspec-spies) and am wondering if there's a way to inspect a spy after all the calls have been made.

For example, If I do something like

```
# setup
Post.stub(:find).with(@post.id).and_return(@post)

do_something_to_call_post_find()

# verify find was called
Post.should have_received(:find).with(@post.id)
```

This works great, but if Post **didn't** receive the expected argument, I get an unhelpful error message (basically "Post should have received find with 123"). Instead, I'd like to see what the actual calls to `` `find `` were.

I can pause right after `do_something_to_call_post_find()`, but is there a way to list all the calls / arguments to a stub/spy?

**Actual use case**
This one caught me up today -- I was expecting `Post.should have_received(:find).with(@post.id)`, where `@post.id is an integer`, my controller test passes the params (including the id) as a string. If I could have inspected the actual calls, I would have seen the difference between `123` and `"123"` and it would have been obvious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This shortfall is no longer an issue in rspec 2.14.0.rc1, which incorporates the improved rspec-spies functionality and is available now on github.

For example, executing the following spec:

```
class Foo
  def self.bar(arg)
  end
end

describe "test" do
  it "should show differences" do
    Foo.stub(:bar)
    Foo.bar(123)
    Foo.should have_received(:bar).with('123')
  end
end
```

generates the following output:

```
F

Failures:

  1) test should show differences
     Failure/Error: Foo.should have_received(:bar).with('123')
       <Foo (class)> received :bar with unexpected arguments
         expected: ("123")
              got: (123)
     # ./foo_spec.rb:10:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.00082 seconds
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./foo_spec.rb:7 # test should show differences
Peters-MacBook-Air-2:botmetrics palfvin$
```

Update: Based on an examination of the definition of the `have_received` matcher at https://github.com/technicalpickles/rspec-spies/blob/master/lib/rspec-spies.rb and some informal testing, it appears that the messages received can be accessed programmatically as follows:

```
Foo.__send__(:__mock_proxy).instance_variable_get("@messages_received")
```

where `Foo` is your test double.

Comment: Thanks, I realize that, but that doesn't really answer the question. Does rspec 2.14 provide a way to inspect spy / stub calls?

Comment: It shows you the difference between the actual and expected value. That's the "shortfall" I was referring to, not the integration.  Are you looking for something else?

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for something that will show me calls made to the method, and their respective arguments. (Not just whether they matched the expected value)

Comment: That's what 2.14.0.rc1 gives you, at least for any failures.

Comment: Great, thanks -- just wondering, is there anyway to inspect it programmatically, instead of relying on the Rspec report? I can see this being helpful for more complicated argument expectations

Comment: See my updated answer. If this still doesn't acceptably answer your question or if you don't at least find the answer helpful, please let me know.